# Ubuntu MATE 14.04: How to disable window maximizing when title bar dragged to top of the desktop

Tags: window, mate, titlebar, maximized

Default behavior on my fresh install of Ubuntu MATE 14.04 has the active window maximize when the title bar is dragged up to the top of the window. I'm not at all a fan of this behavior. I have tried to find a setting in gconf and dconf to turn it off. I also installed CompizConfig Settings Manager and set all the edge behavior there to "None." But this has no effect on the maximizing. Is there any way to turn this off?

Comment: Ehm. Ubuntu Mate is not an official Ubuntu release (yet!) so it will be considered off topic. You might be better of here: http://forums.mate-desktop.org/viewforum.php?f=6 Oh and I doubt if you can alter this :P

Answer (score 4):

Dconf editor: org -> mate -> marco -> general
Untick side-by-side-tiling

Thanks to Rinzwind for pointing me in the right direction -- a resource that never surfaced in my googling. Found the answer here: http://forums.mate-desktop.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3266&p=9964&hilit=window+maximize#p9964

Comment: Actually you don't even need dconf editor for that. System -> Preferences -> Windows -> Placement -> Enable side by side tiling.